# Parse PySpark string column of key-list dictionaries based on separate array column of keys

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently stuck trying to extract the values in the 'keyValue' column below based on the ordered array of keys in the 'Keys' column below.

```
>>> df.select('reference_nbr', 'keyValue', 'Keys').show()
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|    ref_number|                                                     keyValue|                 Keys|
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|          AZQ5|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAX6, TBAXN], key46=[TBARO, TBAZ4, TBABN],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          NXY3|{key39=[TBAX8, TBAX2, TBAXZ], key46=[TBARD, TBAZK, TBAX9],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          QSW6|{key39=[TBAX5, TBAX3, TBAX8], key46=[TBARB, TBAZN, TBAX4],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          LJB7|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAXN, TBAXL], key46=[TBARM, TBAZ2, TBAX3],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          MKH9|{key39=[TBAX4, TBAX9, TBAXV], key46=[TBARB, TBAZB, TBAX1],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          UFG1|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAX6, TBAXQ], key46=[TBARL, TBAZB, TBAX0],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          WDE4|{key39=[TBAX6, TBAX7, TBAX9], key46=[TBARX, TBAX6, TBAX8],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          VRX8|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAX1, TBAX0], key46=[TBARQ, TBAX9, TBAX3],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          CIZ2|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAXC, TBAX2], key46=[TBARA, TBAXQ, TBAX1],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
|          BEO3|{key39=[TBAX9, TBAXQ, TBAX4], key46=[TBARP, TBAXV, TBAX2],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

If I apply the UDF and withColumn() steps below, I can easily query the 'keyValue' column based on a specific key and insert the array of the key's values into a new column.

```
getKey4 = udf(lambda ar1: ar1.get('key4'))
df = df.withColumn("key4Values", getKey4(df["keyValue"]))
```

I am trying to perform the same steps as above but for every key in the order of the 'Keys' column. Desired output:

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|    ref_number|                                                     keyValue|                 Keys|                                          Values|
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|          AZQ5|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAX6, TBAXN], key46=[TBARO, TBAZ4, TBABN],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX4, TBAXQ, TBAXD],[TBAR1, TBAZA, TBABW],...|
|          NXY3|{key39=[TBAX8, TBAX2, TBAXZ], key46=[TBARD, TBAZK, TBAX9],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX5, TBAXA, TBAXC],[TBAR2, TBAZS, TBABE],...|
|          QSW6|{key39=[TBAX5, TBAX3, TBAX8], key46=[TBARB, TBAZN, TBAX4],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX6, TBAXZ, TBAXF],[TBAR3, TBAZD, TBABR],...|
|          LJB7|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAXN, TBAXL], key46=[TBARM, TBAZ2, TBAX3],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX7, TBAXC, TBAXG],[TBAR4, TBAZF, TBABT],...|
|          MKH9|{key39=[TBAX4, TBAX9, TBAXV], key46=[TBARB, TBAZB, TBAX1],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX8, TBAXV, TBAXH],[TBAR5, TBAZG, TBABY],...|
|          UFG1|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAX6, TBAXQ], key46=[TBARL, TBAZB, TBAX0],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX9, TBAXB, TBAXJ],[TBAR6, TBAZH, TBABU],...|
|          WDE4|{key39=[TBAX6, TBAX7, TBAX9], key46=[TBARX, TBAX6, TBAX8],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX0, TBAXN, TBAXK],[TBAR7, TBAZJ, TBABI],...|
|          VRX8|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAX1, TBAX0], key46=[TBARQ, TBAX9, TBAX3],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX2, TBAXM, TBAXL],[TBAR8, TBAZK, TBABO],...|
|          CIZ2|{key39=[TBAX3, TBAXC, TBAX2], key46=[TBARA, TBAXQ, TBAX1],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX3, TBAXA, TBAXO],[TBAR9, TBAZL, TBABP],...|
|          BEO3|{key39=[TBAX9, TBAXQ, TBAX4], key46=[TBARP, TBAXV, TBAX2],...|[key1, key2, key3,...|[[TBAX1, TBAXS, TBAXI],[TBAR0, TBAZQ, TBABZ],...|
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried the method below but I am getting the following error:

```
getKeyValues = udf(lambda ar1, ar2: {ar1.get(x) for x in ar2})
df.withColumn("Values", getKeyValues(df["keyValue"], df["Keys"])).show()

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have tried a different UDF below that also gives the same unicode error:

```
def getKeyVals(ar1, ar2): 
    arr = []
    for x in ar2: 
        arr.append(ar1.get(x, None))
    return arr 
    
udf_split = udf(split, ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn("test", udf_getKeyVals(df['keyValue'], df['Keys'])).show()
```

I have also tried the following function below but I am getting similar errors.
This function comes from the following [MungingData webpage](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/udf-dict-broadcast/)

```
def working_fun(mapping):
    def f(ar1):
        for x in ar1:
            return mapping.get(x)
    return F.udf(f)

df.withColumn("test", working_fun(df["keyValue"])(F.col('Keys'))).show()
```

Would appreciate any tips or recommendations -- thanks!

Updated to include schema and Spark version details below

```
>>> df.select('reference_nbr', 'keyValue', 'Keys').schema.simpleString()
'struct<reference_nbr:string,keyValue:string,Keys:array<string>>'

>>> spark.version
u'2.3.2.3.1.5.6030-1'
```

Comment: Please, copy this command `df.select('reference_nbr', 'keyValue', 'Keys').schema.simpleString()` and paste the output in your question. Also, what's your spark version?

Comment: Appreciate quick reply @Kafels. I have updated the original post to include schema and Spark version information. Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind, could you share your data putting the output from this command `df.select('reference_nbr', 'keyValue', 'Keys').limit(10).collect()` instead?

Comment: Hi @Kafels sorry for getting back late. Unfortunately, the 'keyValue' and 'Keys' columns are very large and I don't think I would be able to post them to Stack Overflow. Please let me know if I can share any other info, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If we convert keyvalue column from string type to map type, we can use map_values function to extract values:

I used UDF to replace = in keyvalues by : so that we can change type to map using ast module.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()


def get_dict(c):
    c = c.replace("=", ":")
    import ast
    dict_value = ast.literal_eval(c)
    return dict_value


get_dict_udf = udf(lambda c: get_dict(c), MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(IntegerType())))

# Sample dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('{"k3"= [6, 5, 4], "k1"= [4, 5, 1], "k8"= [8, 5, 6], "k5"= [7, 4, 3]}',
      ["k1", "k3", "k5", "k8"])]).toDF("keyvalue", "key")

df.withColumn("keyvalue", get_dict_udf("keyvalue")). \
    withColumn("values", sort_array(map_values("keyvalue"))).show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+
|keyvalue                                                            |key             |values                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+
|[k3 -> [6, 5, 4], k5 -> [7, 4, 3], k8 -> [8, 5, 6], k1 -> [4, 5, 1]]|[k1, k3, k5, k8]|[[4, 5, 1], [6, 5, 4], [7, 4, 3], [8, 5, 6]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply, thanks! Unfortunately I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'.  I am guessing I may have to use regex_replace() instead?

Comment: Okay, you can use  but in your case keyvalue column is string right, so here variable 'c' in udf will be of type string and it should accept replace method on 'c'.